# How to input a php variable in a html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to export a variable from a php file in to a html file.
The php file is called example.php and looks like this:

```
<?php
  $array= ['one','two'];
?>
```

The html file is called example2.html and want the $array variable to be the input of var list, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var list = $array
    echo list;

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I am new on this field and don´t know where to start from, thanks for your help.

Comment: `var list = <?php echo $array; ?>` will put the entire PHP array into that Javascript variable, but since it's an array, it will just read "Array". You need to loop over it in PHP and place them into the JavaScript array for each iteration. Also, `echo` is PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Qirel, actually all you need is `<?php echo json_encode($array);?>` which will put it into json, which the JS interpreter can then just read

Comment: @PatrickEvans You're absolutely right!

Comment: i think a php array should build so: `<?php $array= array('one','two'); ?>`

Comment: @Nabi, PHP added array short syntax in 5.4 http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score -2):

You could try `json_encode()` or `implode()` for printing your array from to javascript (html), i have shown you two solution below

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var list = <?="['".implode("','",$array)."']";?>;
    //or
    var list2 = <?=json_encode($array);?>;

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

you've used `echo` in your javascript code that is a syntax error, in javascript you can use `alert()` or `console.log` for testing your varriable, for example in top code you can try this: `alert(list[0]);`

Comment: There is a php function that will create json: `json_encode`, no need to try and manually create json